# Attempting to perform complicated anonymous methods is failing

Tags: linq

### Update (Stupidity Fail)

So then, in all of my convoluted formula code, I neglected the fundamental principles of C#.

> Methods may return a value.

```
static dynamic Construct<T>(T expression){
    return expression;
}
```

Then just use that, instead of a variable ...

```
Method = Construct<Action<Context, string, int>>(
                        (context, key, change) =>
                            {
                                context.Saved[key] += change;

                                Console.WriteLine("{0}'s saved value of {1} was changed by {2}, resulting in {3}",
                                    context.Name, key, change, context.Saved[key]);
                            }
                        )
```

I have a situation where I need to call upon methods that don't exist as compiled methods, but rather need to be able to accept an array of parameters and execute as an anonymous function. I thought I had it worked out, but I am running into an issue with the following..

```
public static IDictionary<string, Function> Expressions =
            new Dictionary<string, Function> {
            {
                "Increase [X] by value of [Y]",
                new Function {
                    Name = "Increase [X] by [Y]",
                    Parameters = 2,
                    Types = new List<Type>{
                        typeof(Param),
                        typeof(Param)
                    },
                    Method = (Expression<Func<Context, Param, Param, bool>>)
                                ((context, x, y) => {
                                    Console.WriteLine("test"); // this is where I need to do stuff... 
                                })
                }
            }
        };
```

I am being told that a `Method name is expected` on this. The problem is that `Context` will be passed in by the object that takes the function and runs its method, because the `Context` object cannot be pre-bound (it has to be late bound). So basically I package up the trailing 2 parameters (`Param`) and (`Param`) in this case and create a function to execute against them.

The database stores those parameters, and then invokes the method passing in the appropriate `Context` as the first parameter by using `Compile().DynamicInvoke(object[] params)`.

Can anyone give me a hand here as to why I cannot put any kind of logic in between my `{ }`?

### UPDATE

Okay, since I've been told this example is unclear, here is an entire program running start to finish that illustrates what I am trying to accomplish.

```
public class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // simple object stored in database.
        var ctx = new Context {
            Name = "Ciel",
            Saved = new Dictionary<string, int> {
                { "First", 10 },
                { "Second", 20 }
            }
        };
        // simple object stored in database.
        var rule = new Rule {
            Equations = new List<Equation> {
                new Equation {
                    Parameters = new List<object>{
                        "First",
                        5
                    },
                    Name = "Increase [X] by value of [Y]"
                }
            }
        };

        // =======================================
        // runtime environment!!!
        // =======================================
        var method = Evaluations.Expressions[rule.Equations[0].Name].Method;
        var parameters = rule.Equations[0].Parameters;

        // insert the specific context as the first parameter.
        parameters.Insert(0, ctx);
        method.DynamicInvoke(parameters.ToArray());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Function {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public dynamic Method { get; set; }
}

public class Equation {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // these objects will be simple enough to serialize.
    public IList<object> Parameters { get; set; }
    public Function Function { get; set; }
}

public class Context {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // this is a crude example, but it serves the demonstration purposes.
    public IDictionary<string, int> Saved { get; set; }
}

public class Rule {
    // again, a crude example.
    public IList<Equation> Equations { get; set; }
}

public static class Evaluations {
    static Action<Context, string, int> expr = (context, key, change) =>
        {
                context.Saved[key] += change;

                Console.WriteLine("{0}'s saved value of {1} was changed by {2}, resulting in {3}",
                    context.Name, key, change, context.Saved[key]);
            };

    public static IDictionary<string, Function> Expressions =
        new Dictionary<string, Function> {
        {
            "Increase [X] by value of [Y]",
            new Function {
                Name = "Increase [X] by [Y]",
                Method = expr
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Your code would be much easier to read if you broke it up into several statements, rather than one huge statement with a single semicolon.

Comment: I've got no idea at this point, I'm just trying to make it compile and figure out what it is expecting.

Comment: @Phil: I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @Phil: Or rather, I'm not sure how to do that in the context of this specific situation. Everything has to happen in this one 'call', so calling multiple methods isn't an option.

Comment: @Phil: And that is what I am kind of trying to do, and it isn't accepting that. I'm trying to have several anonymous functions within it but it isn't allowing them.

Comment: I don't really understand how that would solve anything. Can you illustrate a bit more?

Comment: @Phil: I had not considered sub-functions... my design does not anticipate or consider it, but I suppose there is no reason why I could not do it. In any case, this is very helpful, but it still leaves me confused as to how to execute code within my expression.

Comment: @Phil: Thank you for your assistance. I have taken the advice of both posters here and compiled a more appropriate demonstration of what I aim to accomplish. Please realize that I am well aware this is __massive__ overkill for the calculation in the sample. The goal is to solve more complicated things, but that cannot happen until I can do the very basics, afterall.

Comment: @Phil: can you post your comment as an actual answer so I can accept it? That's what led me to the actual solution.

Comment: Ok, let me compile it. Once I've answered, we can both delete our long list of comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refactor your code to make it a little more readable and manageable, you'll probably be well on your way to solving your problem. Rather than having one mammoth C# statement with a single semicolon, split it up into several lines. Something like this:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Function> Expressions = getExpressions();

private static Dictionary<string, Function> getExpressions()
{   
    var method = (Expression<Func<Context, Param, Param, bool>>)
                    ((context, x, y) => {
                        Console.WriteLine("test"); // this is where I need to do stuff... 
                    })(true);

    var func = new Function()
    {
        Name = "Increase [X] by [Y]",
        Parameters = 2,
        Types = new List<Type>
        {
            typeof(Param),
            typeof(Param)
        },
        Method = method
    };

    var dict = new Dictionary<string, Function>();
    dict["Increase [X] by value of [Y]"] = func;
    return dict;
}
```

Note: my syntax could be incorrect, but you get the general idea.

Comment: Yes, because I am an outright moron I forgot that methods can return a value. Your solution was not the actual answer, but its simplicity made the answer more clear (as you anticipated). The answer was to just create a static `Construct<T>(T expression)` method that returned the parameter passed to it. In doing this, I can create the anonymous methods and assign them in the same step, thus performing any level of cascading neccessary. (I will also note that to make my entire scheme work I had to create an Extension Method to convert my `Parameter` class into straight `object[]` lists)

Comment: Not moronic. Every programmer overlooks obvious things from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

Four problems:

- You're trying to create an expression tree from a lambda expression with a statement body (i.e. braces). C# doesn't allow this - you can only convert a statement lambda into a *delegate*, not an expression tree
- Your lambda body doesn't return a Boolean value
- You're trying to call an `Expression<Func<Context, Param, Param, bool>>` as if it were a method with a `bool` parameter. It's not at all clear what you're trying to do there.
- Even if the third point *were* valid, I suspect you'd need more brackets.

Comment: I am trying to pass in 3 parameters and do an operation to them, but the parameters cannot be known at design time. So how would the better way to write this?

Comment: @Ciel: I'm afraid I really don't understand what you're trying to do well enough to comment. Where are you trying to pass three parameters? What is known at compile-time and what isn't? What does Function look like? Why are you trying to use expression trees?

Comment: I've added the declaration for the Function class. As for what is being passed, that is going to change depending on the context being executed in. That is up to the runtime environment and impossible to discern at design time. The list of parameters is stored in a different class and then the name of the function is saved with them. When those are encountered, the system finds the matching function, takes the parameters, passes the current context needed in as the first parameter and the other stored parameters as the remaining and invokes them.

Comment: So two different things might use the same function for two different sets of the same type parameters, but different values of those parameters.

Comment: The `bool` is just outright required to work because `Func<,>` requires an output parameter. I don't really care about output, I just want to do the work.

Comment: @Ciel: But you're trying to *call* it with `true`, not *return* true. I suspect you want `return true;` *inside* the body. It's still not clear why you need an expression tree, by the way - but you simply won't be able to create an expression tree with braces like this.

Comment: Ok. Could you show me an example of a more appropriate way to build an expression tree, given only the types that will be passed through it? For this specific example, both `Param` objects have a `Value` type that is an `Int32`. This one is just very simple mathematics, but later ones will have more complicated evaluation involved. Any help is greatly appreciated - I am still very new to LINQ in general.

Comment: The only things I can be certain of - the `type` of each parameter, and the behavior that must be implemented. The values of each parameter are not relevant.

Comment: @Ciel: Well your code isn't going to be strongly typed here, because it's using the `Param` type instead of the type that the values really have. But again, the fundamental problem is that you're trying to build a potentially-multi-statement expression tree (using braces). You *can't do that* with the C# compiler expression tree conversion support. .NET 4 *does* allow expression trees with blocks etc, but .NET 3.5 doesn't and even the C# 4 compiler doesn't have support for lambda expression conversion there.

Comment: Then can you think of a more appropriate way to solve this? The problem is that the mathematical functions are too complicated to serialize into the database, but the parameters they require are not. So I store the parameters and call the functions as needed. I've tried using hard-coded methods but the complexity of reflecting  them out roadblocked it.

Comment: @Ciel: I'm afraid we still haven't really got enough context about what you're trying to *do* with this code to suggest alternatives. For example, you still haven't explained why you need an expression tree at all, instead of a simple delegate. I'm going home soon, so may not be able to help much further for a while... but if you could create a short but complete program showing what you're trying to achieve, that would make it a lot easier for *everyone* to help.

Comment: Very well. I have done as you suggested and added an entire program that demonstrates what I need to accomplish. The problem with it is that it would be much less stressful on the maintenance if I were able to declare the expressions inline, instead of having to define them as variables.